# MapWidget crash issue while using on Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, dji-sdk

I am trying to use DJI UX SDK Map-widget in Android Fragment. Its working fine with activity but when i use that widget with fragment its not working.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Here is the code that i have implemented.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment{
    private MapWidget mapWidget;

    public HomeFragment() {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View inflate = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        mapWidget = inflate.findViewById(R.id.map_widget);
        mapWidget = inflate.findViewById(R.id.map_widget);
        mapWidget.initGoogleMap(new MapWidget.OnMapReadyListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(@NonNull DJIMap djiMap) {
            }
        });
        return inflate;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapWidget.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapWidget.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapWidget.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapWidget.onLowMemory();
    }
}
```

**StackTrace**

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bo.o()' on a null object reference
>           at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.cw.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12874021@12.8.74 (040306-204998136):21)
>           at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.w.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12874021@12.8.74 (040306-204998136):12)
>           at fc.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@12874021@12.8.74 (040306-204998136):12)
>           at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
>           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeu.zzb(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzk.onResume(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zza.onResume(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zzh.zzb(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onResume(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.onResume(Unknown Source)
>           at dji.ux.widget.MapWidget.onResume(Unknown Source)
>           at com.xxx.xxx.HomeFragment.onResume(HomeFragment.java)

Comment: try this link , in the end it has some solution -https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/11121

Comment: @Thunder I have implement MapView and its working fine, but i want to use DJI MapWidget. Because they provide more features on map.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View inflate = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    mapWidget = inflate.findViewById(R.id.map_widget);
    mapWidget.initGoogleMap(new MapWidget.OnMapReadyListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(@NonNull DJIMap djiMap) {
        }
    });
    mapWidget.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // add this line

    return inflate;
}
```